# Updating parseGherkinDocument method to the latest version of Cucumber in Java

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, compatibility, gherkin

I'm currently working with Cucumber in Java and have a method, parseGherkinDocument, that uses GherkinDocument. I've been facing issues when trying to update this method to align with the latest version of Cucumber. Here is the existing method:

```
private static GherkinDocument parseGherkinDocument(TestSourceRead testSource) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(testSource, "testSource cannot be null");
    String source = testSource.getSource();
    List<Envelope> sources = singletonList(fromResource(source, testSource.getUri().toString()));
    List<Envelope> envelopes = Gherkin
            .fromSources(sources, true, true, true, () -> String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID())).collect(toList());
    GherkinDocument gherkinDocument = envelopes.stream()
        .map(Envelope::getGherkinDocument).filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
    return gherkinDocument;
}
```

I would like to know how I can update this method to be compatible with the latest version of Cucumber. Are there any changes in the new version that affect how GherkinDocument should be used?

I wrote a method that uses Cucumber's GherkinDocument class to parse Gherkin test sources in Java. My method worked fine with an older version of Cucumber. When I updated to the latest version of Cucumber, I expected my custom method to continue functioning correctly, or at least with minimal modifications. However, it seems to be incompatible with the new version, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to update it. I've reviewed the latest Cucumber documentation but couldn't find clear guidance on how to update the usage of GherkinDocument

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/303a14694aadfa55ac2a40b7363a77421ffaafcb/cucumber-core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/plugin/TestSourcesModel.java#L100